# how to select radio button in twitter by selenium webdriver with python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

select radio button in twitter such as picture below  by selenium webdriver with python?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the developer tools of the twitter page, you can see that the dialog contains an iframe (id = "new-report-flow-frame"). You should first switch to that iframe before searching for a radio button

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("new-report-flow-frame"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[value='illegal_product']")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first switch to popup window with something like

`driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])`